# Swig: How to pass "FILE" type from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, file, java-native-interface, swig

I have a function in C++ for which I need to create a wrapper in Java. The function expects an input parameter of type FILE (from stdio). I don't believe that Swig can automatically appropriate an interface in Java without some manual engineering in the swig interface file - I might be wrong.

Here is what I have --

C++ (theHeader.h):

```
#include <cstdio>

class SampleClass 
{
 public:
  SampleClass(FILE* file) : file(file)
  {
  }

  private:
  FILE* file;
};
```

I have tried compiling, but it results in the creation of Swig pointer type: SWIGTYPE_p_FILE, which doesn't help me in passing the FILE type argument from Java to C++.

Comment: A `FILE` type is implementation-defined for the particular C++ compiler and version you're using.  Change compilers or compiler version or compiler options, you get a different `FILE`.  So I don't know what you're trying to accomplish given that it isn't even safe to do between C++ modules compiled with differing compilers / options.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not quite. The `FILE *` pointer returned from a native call to `fopen()` will depend on the C run-time library linked into the JVM.  If the native code does anything but treat a `FILE *` as anything but an opaque pointer, it's non-portable anyway.  In some implementations, a `FILE *` actually *is* opaque for the very purpose of preventing such abuse.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, if you pass only the pointer and work with just the pointer.  What you can't pass is `FILE` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use SWIG for this?  This is pretty trivial to do directly with JNI (assuming pointers fit into `jlong` values for your system's architecture, which is usually a pretty safe assumption):

Java:

```
// get an instance of the native C++ class
static native long getClassInstance();

static native long getClassInstance( long file );

// get the native FILE * from the class instance
static native long getFileFromClass( long cls );

// close the FILE *
static native void closeFile( long file );
```

You'd use it like this:

```
long file = 0;
long cls = getClassInstance();
if ( cls != 0 )
{
    file = getFileFromClass( cls );
}
```

Or, if you already have the `FILE *` from native code:

```
long instance = getClassInstance( file );
```

Native C++ code would look something like this (I'm not bothering to do the full `javac` work from the above Java code):

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL some_class_getClassInstance(
    JNIenv *env, jclass cl )
{
    myClass *cls = new MyClass();
    return( ( jlong )( intptr_t ) cls );
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL some_class_getClassInstance(
    JNIenv *env, jclass cl, jlong file )
{
    FILE *fp = ( FILE * )( intptr_t ) file;
    myClass *cls = new MyClass( fp );
    return( ( jlong )( intptr_t ) cls );
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL some_class_getFileFromClass(
    JNIenv *env, jclass cl, jlong cls )
{
    myClass *instance = ( myClass * )( intptr_t ) cls;

    FILE *fp = myClass->getFile();

    return( ( jlong )( intptr_t ) fp );
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL some_class_name_closeFile(
    JNIenv *env, jclass cls, jlong file )
{
    FILE *fp = ( FILE * ) ( intptr_t ) file;
    fclose( fp );
}
```

Note that the code assumes that the native definition of `NULL` is always a zero value.  Technically, JNI makes a C call, not a C++ call, so `NULL` might not be guaranteed to always be actually defined to be zero, depending on your architecture and how you code up your interface between Java and native code.  So to be fully standard compliant, a `NULL` pointer result would cause the `jlong` value returned to Java to be explicitly set to zero.  The reverse works because a zero value is defined by the C Standard to be *a* `NULL` pointer value that compares equal to the defined `NULL` pointer constant. (Note that there can be more than one "`NULL` pointer value" even though there's only one definition of `NULL` itself.)

Comment: Since this is related to Swig, any indication of how you would attempt to do it in Swig? I have a fairly large code base, and the `FILE*` case is one of several cases.

Comment: @nikk How about treating the `FILE *` parameter as a simple `long` on the Java side, cast it on the native side as above, and pretty much bypass SWIG's making the problem harder than it has to be?

Comment: @nikk This solution *is* exactly what SWIG is doing for your, for free inside the `SWIGTYPE_p_FILE`, (or any opaque pointer for that matter) but with the added bonus that what SWIG does is type safe and strongly typed. Your solution won't trivially scale for large codebases and would need copy and pasting to every use of `FILE*`. If your aim is to support this transparently (e.g. by accepting any `BufferedReader` including ones from `javax.net.Socket`s that simply aren't files) across a reasonable subset of platforms (e.g. Win32 API calls and POSIX) you can do something much more flexible.

Comment: @Flexo nice to connect with you again. Thanks for the additional pointers!